# Error message on startup

Tags: 18.04

Running ubuntu 18.04 on startup I get a message that says "System problem detected. Do you want to repair the problem". After i click on report the problem the message disappears. When I start my computer the next time the message reappears.

Comment: It's "Do you want to *report* the problem," not 'repair'. If you want to know more about the problem, look in your /var/crash directory.

Comment: https://www.techdrivein.com/2012/08/how-to-disable-system-program-problem.html will help

Comment: When it happened once before the answer i got was try "sudo rm-rf/var/crash/* and it worked but it will not work now.

Comment: Sorry I misread it.

Comment: Deleting the .crash file is like hanging a picture to cover a hole in the wall. It makes folks feel better, but doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: user535733 your comment seems to me to be saying it is not serious like spyware or a virus and is just a nuisance. If that is the case I won't worry about. .